# "for" loop for Google Spreadsheet values not looping

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently writing a statistic spreadsheet script for my guild, which reads out the class of one person and counts it on the statistic sheet.

For some reason the `for` loops aren't working. When I execute the script, it does nothing.  Everything before the `for` loop seems to work.  I have used the debugger, and set a debug point from the point of the `for` loop and the window is opening and closing after like 1 second.

This is my code as of now:

```
function addToStatistik() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();          

  var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Raid Montag");       
  var source_range_names = source_sheet.getRange("C4:C13");
  var source_range_setup_boss1 = source_sheet.getRange("M4:M13");

  var target_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Statistik");       
  var target_range_names = target_sheet.getRange("A4:A31");
  var target_range_boss1 = target_sheet.getRange("K4:S31");


  target_sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue("Debug1"); //testing stuff
  for (var i=0; i < source_range_names.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < target_range_names.length; j++) {
      if (source_range_names[i][0] == target_range_names[j][0]) {
        if (source_range_setup_boss1[i][0].indexOf("War") > -1) {
          target_sheet.getRange(9,5).setValue("TEST");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Someone can find any errors in there? I can't find anything and google also isnt helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the range, but not the values.  This line:

```
var source_range_names = source_sheet.getRange("C4:C13");
```

gets a range, but not any values.

Should be:

```
var source_range_names = source_sheet.getRange("C4:C13").getValues();
```

The outer loop never loops.  There is no `length` of a range.

```
for (var i=0; i < source_range_names.length; i++) {
```

You don't need to change the above line, but currently the variable `source_range_names` is a range, and not a 2D array of values.

Comment: Thank you! Now that you said this, it makes sense, but I just didn't think of that. Can I also use the ranges that I set above with f.e. .setValue later, if I just append .getValues() now on each range?

Comment: If you need to use the range (or any variable) more than once, you may want to have a variable just for the range.  Then you can reuse that variable.  Whether you should create a variable for something depends on  how many times you need to re-use it, and maybe readability of the code.  You may want to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` to cause pending changes to be updated if you have code that is reading values very soon after making changes.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll look into this. Another question, this isn't the same topic, but is it somehow possible to get a range within a range? I have   "var target_range_boss1 = target_sheet.getRange("K4:S31");" for example now and want to set one Cell in this Range, how to achieve that?

Comment: You can get *one* cell as a range inside of another range with `getCell()`  [Apps Script documentation - getCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer))  You can't get a multi-cell range inside of a range.

Comment: okay, but it seems as it isnt possible to do something like this: "target_range_boss1.getCell(2,8).setValue("Test");" ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  The `getCell()` method returns a range, and you can set a value on a range.

Answer (score 0):

Before you iterate you need to get the values of the range, to achieve this you need to use the method [**getValues()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) or [**getDisplayValues()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues):

```
function leFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();          
  var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Raid Montag"); 
  var source_range_names = source_sheet.getRange("A1:C13");
  var values_range_names = source_range_names.getDisplayValues();

  Logger.log(values_range_names);

  for (var i=0; i < values_range_names.length; i++) {
    // Do Something
  }

}
```